# How to evaluate Parenthesis using Stacks on String in C#

Tags: c#, stack

I have a string expression, i need to evaluate it for following conditions:

```
("Hello" OR "World") AND (("Go" OR "Stay") NOT "Stop")
```

How can i evaluate the above expression using stacks? The above expression is being carried out on a text file.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Those operators normally only make sense when they have *bool* operands.  How you are going to make it sensible with *strings* is going to require a **lot** of imagination.

Comment: i have tried to split it and store it in 3 stacks as parentheses,  operator and operand. but i could not find a way to evaluate it according to the parenthesis

Comment: ("Hello" OR "World) AND (("Go" OR "Stay") is always false! - But have a look at the interpreter pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/net/interpreter-design-pattern

Comment: its just an example, didnt think about its validity :)

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is an algorithm to evaluate infix expression using a stack. If you look at the detail example you might fit it according to your problem

Comment: it would also help if you could describe the process a little more in detail. for example: what does "expression is being carried out on a text file" mean exactly?

Comment: i need to search a file/files according to an expression ex: "Hello" OR "World". Result of this expression should return text file/files containing the word hello or world. problem arose with the use of parenthesis. dont know how to evaluate them on string input

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Irony](https://irony.codeplex.com/), which allows you to define your own expressions and tell the interpreter how to evaluate it. I used this in my project, similar with your case. I can't post the original code because it's for commercial use, but it looks like this:

```
class CommandGrammar : Grammar    //define your own grammar
{
    public CommandGrammar(bool caseSensitive = false) 
        : base(caseSensitive)
    {
        var Command = new NonTerminal("Command");
        Command.Rule = ToTerm("GO") | "STOP" | "STAY";   
                        //these 3 tokens are called "command"

        var And = new NonTerminal("And", ToTerm("AND"));
        var Or = new NonTerminal("Or", ToTerm("OR"));
        var Not = new NonTerminal("Not", ToTerm("NOT"));
                       //define 3 logical operators

        var UnaryOperator = new NonTerminal("UnaryOperator");
        var BinaryOperator = new NonTerminal("BinaryOperator");
        var SimpleExp = new NonTerminal("SimpleExp");
        var ParenthesizedExp = new NonTerminal("ParenthesizedExp");
        var UnaryExp = new NonTerminal("UnaryExp");
        var BinaryExp = new NonTerminal("BinaryExp");
        var Exp = new NonTerminal("Exp");
                  //there are some possible expressions

        //here are the rules for parsing the expression
        UnaryOperator.Rule = Not;            
        BinaryOperator.Rule = And | Or;
        SimpleExp.Rule = Command;
        ParenthesizedExp.Rule = "(" + Exp + ")";
        UnaryExp.Rule = (UnaryOperator + SimpleExp) | (UnaryOperator + ParenthesizedExp);
        BinaryExp.Rule = Exp + BinaryOperator + Exp;
        Exp.Rule = SimpleExp | ParenthesizedExp | UnaryExp | BinaryExp;
    }
}
```

The above code is just an example, showing how the library parses your expressions with your own grammar. You need to look into the library yourself, and implement the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t compare Strings with boolean expression like & |...
However, what I think you were trying to say is whether the stack contains the mentioned strings, you can check with the method contains(obj) which returns a boolean:

```
class Program
{
    const string a = "Hello";
    const string b = "World";
    const string c = "Go";
    const string d = "Stay";
    const string e = "Stop"; 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stack st = new Stack();

        st.Push(a);
        st.Push(b);
        st.Push(c);
        st.Push(d);
        st.Push(e);

        if ((st.Contains("Hello") || st.Contains("World")) && ((st.Contains("Go") || st.Contains("Stay")) && (st.Contains("Stop") == false)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        } // no success
        //Remove "Stop" to match the expression
        st.Pop();
        if ((st.Contains("Hello") || st.Contains("World")) && ((st.Contains("Go") || st.Contains("Stay")) && (st.Contains("Stop") == false)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        } //success
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i need to evaluate according to the parenthesis